# Accessing Java Packages in different Drives

Tags: java, windows

Consider if I have got a Package in my C:\x\y\z and another package in D:\m\n\o.
How can I access them in my java program? Do I need to set any path?

Comment: You have to set a classpath whether you use one drive or two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set your classpath to add each directory. Assuming that your package structure begins underneath each of those directories:

```
java -classpath C:\x\y\z;D:\m\n\o <MyClassName>
```

See [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#options).